# When JS passes numeric values as arguments to Solidity function, why is it better to wrap them in quotes?

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I defined a function in Solidity:

```
function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {}
```

Then call the function with argument `7` in JavaScript:

```js
contract.store(7);
```

But, according to the [Patrick Collins JS video](https://youtu.be/gyMwXuJrbJQ?t=27092), it's better to wrap number `7` with quotes like this:

```js
contract.sotre("7");
```

So here are two things confused me:

1. Why it's better to wrap number with quotes when passing a number to a solidity contract function?
2. Why ehter.js can automatically convert string to number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript supports a smaller set of numbers than Solidity. Specificially, the maximal safe value in JS is [2^53 - 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), while the maximal numeric value in Solidity is `2^256`.

So if you were to for example transfer 1 token with 18 decimals, the resulting decimal value that you'd need to pass to the Solidity contract is `1000000000000000000` - which is somewhere between `2^59` and `2^60`, already higher than the maximal safe JS integer of `2^53 - 1`.

For this reason, ethers.js and other JS smart contract libraries accept numeric values either as native JS string or an instance of a helper library called [BigNumber](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/) - but not as integers.

Note: Some libraries in some versions might be able to convert the native integer to a string or BigNumber at first. But generally, it's always safer to pass the non-integer values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand that the smart contract libraries don't accept integers as numeric values, but native JS string or an instance of BigNumber.